# Calculate the top 5 and summarize them by store

Tags: sas

Let's say I have stores all around the world and I want to know what was my top losses sales across the world per store. What is the code for that?!

here is my try:

```
proc sort data= store out=sorted_store;
by store descending amount;
run;
```

and

```
data calc1;
 do _n_=1 by 1 until(last.store);
  set sorted_store;
  by store;
  if _n_ <= 5 then "Sum_5Largest_Losses"n=sum(amount);
 end;
run;
```

but this just prints out the 5:th amount and not 1.. TO .. 5! and I really don't know how to select the top 5 of EACH store . I think a kind of group by would be a perfect fit. But first things, first. How do I selct i= 1...5 ? And not just = 5?

Comment: If you use the `sum(,)` function with only one variable there is nothing to sum!

Answer (score 0):

There is also way of doing it with proc sql:

```
data have;
    input store$ amount;
    datalines;
A 100
A 200
A 300
A 400
A 500
A 600
A 700
B 1000
B 1100
C 1200
C 1300
C 1400
D 600
D 700
E 1000
E 1100
F 1200
;
run;

proc sql outobs=4; /* limit to first 10 results */
  select store, sum(amount) as TOTAL_AMT
  from have
  group by 1
  order by 2 desc; /* order them to the TOP selection*/ 
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

The data step `sum(,)` function adds up its arguments. If you only give it one argument then there is nothing to actually sum so it just returns the input value.

```
data calc1;
  do _n_=1 by 1 until(last.store);
    set sorted_store;
    by store;
    if _n_ <= 5 then Sum_5Largest_Losses=sum(Sum_5Largest_Losses,amount);
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend learning the basic methods before getting into DOW loops.

- Add a counter so you can find the first 5 of each store
- As the data step loops the sum accumulates
- Output sum for counter=5

```
proc sort data= store out=sorted_store;
by store descending amount;
run; 


data calc1;
  set sorted_store;
  by store;
  *if first store then set counter to 1 and total sum to 0;
  if first.store then do ; 
       counter=1;
       total_sum=0; 
   end;
  *otherwise increment the counter;
  else counter+1;
  *accumulate the sum if counter <= 5;
  if counter <=5 then total_sum = sum(total_sum, amount);
    *output only when on last/5th record for each store;
  if counter=5 then output; 
run;
```